# Assign Array to String in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave

How to assign array to String? I want to convert XML to CSV. My dataweave returning array. I want to convert it into CSV.

Transform Message Code:

```
%input payload application/xml
%output application/java
---
(payload.catalog.*category-assignment default []) groupBy $.@product-id pluck {

        product-id:$$,
        cat-id: $.@category-id joinBy ":",
        primary-flag:$.primary-flag,
        field3:$.@category-id when $.primary-flag[0] == "true"  otherwise ""

    }
```

My payload is like:

```
[{
    product - id = D198561, cat - id = 1111, primary - flag = null, field3 =
}, {
    product - id = D198563, cat - id = 30033, primary - flag = [true], field3 = [30033]
}, {
    product - id = D198566, cat - id = 0933: 2104: 7043, primary - flag = null, field3 =
}]
```

I want output in CSV with respect to payload as:

`Field1: product-id, Field2:cat-id,Field3:field3`

---

Its giving error in field 3 as it is array like  field3=[30033].
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not go straight to CSV instead using application/csv? You can check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8rC0sktwyY.

Comment: I have to do condition checking on incoming xml file.. so I have to create map of the data first and then convert it into csv